# AWS S3 bucket clean up but save certain number of folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So, currently inside an S3 bucket, I store the javascript bundle file outputted from webpack. Here is a sample folder structure

```
- s3_bucket_name
  - javascript_bundle
     - 2018_10_11
     - 2018_10_09
     - 2018_10_08
     - 2018_10_07
     - 2018_10_06
     - 2018_10_05
```

So I want to clean up the folders and only save 5 folders. (the folder name are date of deployment) I am unable to clean up by the date since it's possible we may not deploy for a long time. 
Because of this, I am unable to use lifecycle methods.

For example, if I set the expiration date to 30 days, S3 will automatically remove all the folders if we don't deploy for 30 days, then all the javascript file will be removed and the site won't work.

Is there a way to accomplish this using AWS CLI?

The requirements are

1. Delete folder by date
2. Keep a minimum of 5 folders

For example, given the following folders and we want to delete folders older than 30 days while keeping at least 5 folders

```
- 2018_10_11
- 2018_09_09
- 2018_08_08
- 2018_07_07
- 2018_06_06
- 2018_05_05
```

The only one that will be deleted is `2018_05_05`.

I don't see any options to do this via `aws s3 rm` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which folders to delete, but there is no option in the AWS CLI to specify which folders you *do not* want to delete.

This requirement would best be solved by writing a script (eg in Python) that can retrieve a list of the Bucket contents and then apply some logic to which objects should be deleted.

In Python, using `boto3`, [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) can return a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which is effectively a list of folders. You could then determine which folders should be kept and then delete the objects in all other paths.